# Reading a big multi GB size text file in php

Tags: php, file-handling

I have a 197gb text file that I want to read and push the contents into MySql database. I know, I can't put that big file in PHP buffer and read it as whole, So I want to read few hundred lines as a time and keep on reading next and next to read the whole file.

I am trying it with this but the page returns nothing

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$handle = fopen("./data/200gbfile.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line . "<br />";
        if ($i > 100) {
            exit;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Error Opeing File!";
}
?>
```

Is there a limit of the max file size to be handled in php setting?

> EDIT: for the 197gb file in question, fopen is failing to return anything and
>   the output page is just going blank.

Comment: This [link](https://likegeeks.com/process-large-files-using-php/) might help you

Comment: try `@fopen("./data/200gbfile.txt", "r")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file in chunks to save memory:

For example:

```
$fd = @fopen("./data/200gbfile.txt", "r");

while (!feof($fd)) {
   $data = fread($fd, 1024); // read the file in 1024kb chunks
   // handle current data (read line by line for example)
}
fclose($fd);
```

But no idea if that works with a file with 100Gbytes+.

```
Edit: @ with fopen is required as suggested by Roman.
```

Comment: for the 197gb file in question, fopen is failing to return anything and the output page is just going blank.

Comment: What happens when you echo out the data (after reading first chunk) - does it read anything? What contains your txt file, csv?

Comment: It doesn't read anything with fopen. I mean it return false as fopen does when it fail.

Comment: Normally it should work with large files with fopen, because it supports reading files as stream. But not sure how to handle that large files. Maybe it would be better to use an other language (with more performance for such things) - Java/C# for example. PHP is not the best choice if you really need to read files with 200! Gbytes.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');` to set size accordingly but i don't wether it will handle such huge file. never tested that..